# Making a div scroll with the page after a certain distance

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-float

I have a web page set up with 225px of header space and then the body begins. I have a floating div that I want to follow with the body as the page gets scrolled down. The div follows but I dont want it to start until the user has scrolled past the header. Here is a picture example:

[image: image example]

Once the user has scrolled past all the red (225px), then the blue div should being scrolling with the page.

The current problem is that the div begins moving the second the user scrolls through the header and ends up 225px below the top of the page.

I believe something like this is what I need, but it doesn't seem to do anything (at least in chrome)

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 255)
    {
        //begin to scroll
        $("#floating_list").css("position","fixed");
        $("#floating_list").css("top",0);
    }
    else
    {
        //lock it back into place
        $("#floating_list").css("position","relative");
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You must put in some code. Otherwise, people will close this question.

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. Have a demo of it not working? Perhaps on jsFiddle?

Comment: Have you tried with $(document) instead of $(window) ?

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4CJSh/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't set any event listener. Include JQuery and here's the working code:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function(){ 
// or as a shorthand $(document).scroll(function(){
if($(document).scrollTop() > 255)
    {
        //begin to scroll
        $("#floating_list").css("position","fixed");
        $("#floating_list").css("top",0);
    }
    else
    {
        //lock it back into place
        $("#floating_list").css("position","relative");
    }
});
```

Comment: Changing it to document fixed it. Thanks!